# SQL Server query on php

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm begginner in this field so I need help.
I want to get integer value from this select. When I run this query in sql server - it returns correct value *(so that part is okay)*

My idea is to get integer value of $select -> put it in $value variable and use it after that.

Here is working sql expression:

```
$select = "SELECT COUNT (*) broj (SELECT a.CaseNo as CaseNo,
        b.Naruc as Naruc,
        b.Opis as Opis,
        b.Vrijednost as cijena,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),b.Datumpn, 127) as datum_predaje,
        (case when b.Kn IS NULL then 0 when b.Kn IS not null then b.Kn end) as kat1,
        (case when b.Kn2 IS NULL then 0 when b.Kn2 IS not null then b.Kn2 end) as kat2,
        (case when b.Kn3 IS NULL then 0 when b.Kn3 IS not null then b.Kn3 end) as kat3,
        a.DateInserted as datum_unosa
    FROM [Therefore].[dbo].[za_slanje_maila] a, [Therefore].[dbo].[TheCase1] b
    WHERE CONVERT(date,a.DateInserted) = '".$today."'
    AND a.DateInserted < '".$today3."'
    AND a.CaseNo = b.CaseNo
    AND b.Naruc is not null
    AND b.Opis is not null
    AND b.Vrijednost is not null
    AND b.Datum_predaje is not null) broj";
```

After that, I tryed this

```
$data_api = sqlsrv_query($conn, $select, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
```

And then I try to call

```
$value = $data_api['broj']
```

***- but that is empty.***

How can I assign that value to the variable $value?

Thanks.

Comment: Before anything, you ***need*** to learn about parametrised queries. What you have there is a major injection concern. I also suggest you stop using the old 1989 `JOIN` syntax; it was superseded some 28 years ago. [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Good aliasing is also a *must* for easy to read and understandable code: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Answer (score 0):

[`sqlsrv_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php) doesn't return an array yet, but statement resource (or `false` on error). You can then use this resource to get the data array with [sqlsrv_fetch_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) function.